# How can I return an empty Json from Controller?

Tags: c#, json, collections, controller

developers!

I found a similar question on `stackoverflow` but the solution didn't help me. So I am posting again.

I am trying to return a collection of type Json from a Controller. But instead of `null` I want to return an Empty collection like `Enumerable.Empty<>()`. I searched on other websites also but nothing helped me.

I tried `new EmptyResult()` (solution from `stackoverflow` but it didn't work)

Here is the code.

```
public JsonResult GetOrderDetail(int? id)
{
if(id.HasValue)
{
    var first = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomerRepository>().Method();
    var second = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IShopRepository>().Method();
    return Json(new
    {
        first,
        second
    }
}
return null;
}
```

So, here instead of null I want to return an Empty Collection. Is it possible? How can I do it?
I am new to C#. I am sorry if the question is silly or wrong in the first place.

Comment: Please update your question to show the **exact JSON** you want to return. _Don't use words like collection etc - the **actual string** is what we need to see._

Comment: could you please explain `I want to return an Empty Collection` but empty collection of what? either string, int, or your model ?

Comment: try this `public JsonResult GetJson()
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            return Json(list ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: @ershoaib I wanted to return an empty collection of type Json. I updated the question actually because of the first comment by mjwills

Comment: try this `return Json(new object[] { new object() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @ershoaib I found the solution. I have answered the question. Please check. Also I have replied to your comment for an `Empty Collection` of what? Please check that too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Json.NET

When using [`Json.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can use and empty [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) or [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)

This is the most common and recommended method to use JSON in C#. It can be added to a project via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Comment: You could return an empty JSON object with `return JObject()` or return an empty JSON array with `return JArray()` _(add the proper Json.NET imports or package prefixes, depending on your project)_.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I only had to do this. In place of `null`, I wrote `Json(new EmptyResult())`. So the method will eventually return nothing but not a null value.

Comment: What actual JSON does this return (if you look at the http request)?

Comment: @mjwills If the Json objects `first` and `second` hold no data the method `GetOrderDetail()` will return nothing. Since the collection is empty it'll give an Empty result.

Comment: So `""`? `[]`? Something else? Can you check in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Developer Tools show the response returning `{}` - not what I'm looking for